# No OpenID endpoint found - DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetopenauth

I am trying to make an OpenID authentication with SSO. I'm using DotNetOpenAuth as a framework for that.

It's strange, because I have made Authentication without SSO, without problems, but my second app has problems

Here is my Page_Load function:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            UriBuilder returnToBuilder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
            returnToBuilder.Path = "/login.aspx";
            returnToBuilder.Query = null;
            returnToBuilder.Fragment = null;
            Uri returnTo = returnToBuilder.Uri;
            returnToBuilder.Path = "/";
            Realm realm = returnToBuilder.Uri;

            var response = relyingParty.GetResponse();
            if (response == null) {
                if (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
                    // The user must have been directed here because he has insufficient
                    // permissions to access something.
                    this.MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
                } else {
                    // Because this is a sample of a controlled SSO environment,
                    // we don't ask the user which Provider to use... we just send
                    // them straight off to the one Provider we trust.
                    var request = relyingParty.CreateRequest(
                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SsoProviderOPIdentifier"],
                        realm,
                        returnTo);
                    var fetchRequest = new FetchRequest();
                    fetchRequest.Attributes.AddOptional(RolesAttribute);
                    request.AddExtension(fetchRequest);
                    request.RedirectToProvider();
                }
            } else {
                switch (response.Status) {
                    case AuthenticationStatus.Canceled:
                        this.errorLabel.Text = "Login canceled.";
                        break;
                    case AuthenticationStatus.Failed:
                        this.errorLabel.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(response.Exception.Message);
                        break;
                    case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
                        IList<string> roles = null;
                        var fetchResponse = response.GetExtension<FetchResponse>();
                        if (fetchResponse != null) {
                            if (fetchResponse.Attributes.Contains(RolesAttribute)) {
                                roles = fetchResponse.Attributes[RolesAttribute].Values;
                            }
                        }
                        if (roles == null) {
                            roles = new List<string>(0);
                        }

                        // Apply the roles to this auth ticket
                        const int TimeoutInMinutes = 100; // TODO: look up the right value from the web.config file
                        var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                            2,
                            response.ClaimedIdentifier,
                            DateTime.Now,
                            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(TimeoutInMinutes),
                            false, // non-persistent, since login is automatic and we wanted updated roles
                            string.Join(";", roles.ToArray()));

                        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket));
                        Response.SetCookie(cookie);
                        Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] ?? FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

And here is my Web.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection, DotNetOpenAuth.Core">
      <section name="messaging" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.MessagingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="reporting" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.ReportingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="openid" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OpenIdElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="oauth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OAuthElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <dotNetOpenAuth>

    <messaging>
      <untrustedWebRequest>
        <whitelistHosts>
          <!-- since this is a sample, and will often be used with localhost -->
          <add name="localhost" />
          <!-- Uncomment to enable communication with localhost (should generally not activate in production!) -->
<!--          <add name="localhost" />-->
        </whitelistHosts>
      </untrustedWebRequest>
    </messaging>


    <!-- Allow DotNetOpenAuth to publish usage statistics to library authors to improve the library. -->
    <reporting enabled="true" />
    <!-- This is an optional configuration section where aspects of dotnetopenauth can be customized. -->
    <!-- For a complete set of configuration options see http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/configuration-options/ -->
    <openid>
      <relyingParty>
        <security requireSsl="false">
          <!-- Uncomment the trustedProviders tag if your relying party should only accept positive assertions from a closed set of OpenID Providers. -->
          <trustedProviders rejectAssertionsFromUntrustedProviders="true">
                        <add endpoint="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id" />
                    </trustedProviders>
        </security>
        <behaviors>
          <!-- The following OPTIONAL behavior allows RPs to use SREG only, but be compatible
                             with OPs that use Attribute Exchange (in various formats). -->
          <add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" />
        </behaviors>
      </relyingParty>
    </openid>
  </dotNetOpenAuth>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="SsoProviderOPIdentifier" value="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id" />
    <add key="SsoProviderOPEndpoint" value="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id" />
  </appSettings>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication3-20140717151453;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication3-20140717151453.mdf" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" />
  </system.net>
  <uri>
    <!-- The uri section is necessary to turn on .NET 3.5 support for IDN (international domain names),
             which is necessary for OpenID urls with unicode characters in the domain/host name.
             It is also required to put the Uri class into RFC 3986 escaping mode, which OpenID and OAuth require. -->
    <idn enabled="All" />
    <iriParsing enabled="true" />
  </uri>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I heard that it can be proxy problem, but I have set up defaultProxy. The same proxy configuration works on different solution, on same machine.

Could you take a look on it and say, whats wrong with that?

Comment: You have `requireSSL="false"` on your security element, but your endpoint goes to https. I don't know much about openID, but that seems somewhat contradictory. You don't require SSL, but you force your endpoint connection to use it?

Comment: I have same on second solution, and it's working. I have also tried to switch `requireSSL` to `true`, without success

Comment: use VS to compare the 2 configurations and see if there are any differences that are not needed.

Comment: Checked it twice. No serious differences. Is it possible that problem is that this second(working) app is in MVC, and this is not?

Comment: Normally MVC shouldn't make any difference. I suggest that you first try to reduce your code to the basics: create a new asp.net forms application and make it so that google authentication works with that. don't include any code like forcing the user to use that specific provider. Make something that works and allows basic google authentication. then add the rest of the functionality one step at a time. Since you're still developing, you have the luxury to delay functionality until what you have works.